# Convert an "AsIs" class to data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

The data is from

```
 datasetname="riboflavin"
  data(riboflavin, package = "hdi")
  Y=as.numeric(riboflavin$y)-1
  mydata=data.frame(Y,X)

 #X now is 71*4088 
str(X) 
 'AsIs' num [1:71, 1:4088] 8.49 7.64 8.09 7.89 6.81 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:71] "b_Fbat107PT24.CEL" "b_Fbat107PT30.CEL" "b_Fbat107PT48.CEL" "b_Fbat107PT52.CEL" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:4088] "AADK_at" "AAPA_at" "ABFA_at" "ABH_at" ... 
#71*1
 str(Y) 
 num [1:71] -7.64 -7.95 -8.93 -9.29 -8.31 ...

 dim(mydata)
[1] 71  2
```

why dim(mydata) is not  71*4089? How to obtain a data.frame of (X,Y) with a dimensionality with 71*4089？

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num [1:71, 1:4088]` means `riboflavin$x` is a matrix. `cbind`ing modified column `y` to matrix `x` should solve the problem.

```
res <- as.data.frame(cbind(Y=riboflavin$y - 1, X=riboflavin$x))
dim(res)
# [1]   71 4089
```